# Optimizing nested functions for quadrature routine

Tags: python, function, performance, numpy, processing-efficiency

I wrote the code below in Python to create a function that integrates `func(x+t**(1/2) * z)*...` with respect to `z`, where I want to call the function for some `x`.

This is part of a bigger code and in order to make the whole program go faster I wondered if there was a way to optimize the way `pregau` works.

```
def gauss(func, t):
    def gauss(x):
        def pregau(z):
            arg = x + t ** (1 / 2) * z
            return func(arg) * math.exp(-(z**2)/2)

        integration = integrate.quad(pregau, -np.inf, np.inf, epsabs=0.001)[0]
        return (2 * math.pi) ** (-1/2) * integration

    return gauss
```

I thought about interpolating it on the whole space, but maybe any of you have better ideas to solve this problem?